# Conditionally include extensions?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

There's a `ifconfig` sphinx extension -- and it allows for conditional inclusion of *content*. I'm looking for a way to conditionally include extensions. My best try is just to give a list of extensions with a `-D` option to `sphinx-build`:

```
sphinx-build -b singlehtml -d _build/doctrees -D html_theme=empty -D "extensions=['sphinx.ext.autodoc', 'sphinx.ext.viewcode', 'sphinx.ext.numfig', 'sphinx.ext.ifconfig', 'cloud_sptheme.ext.table_styling', 'sphinx.ext.htmlmath']" . _build/wkA
```

but it doesn't work.

The problem is to conditionally include `sphinx.ext.htmlmath` or `sphinxcontrib.mathml`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `-t <tag>` http://sphinx-doc.org/invocation.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-t

e.g. Invoke sphinx like this (See `-t use_htmlmath`):

```
sphinx-build -b singlehtml -d _build/doctrees \
   -D html_theme=empty -t use_htmlmath . _build/wkA
```

Have this code in `conf.py`

```
if tags.has('use_htmlmath'):
    # use supplied =t use_htmlmath
    extensions.append('sphinx.ext.htmlmath')
else:
    #fall back
    extensions.append('sphinxcontrib-mathml')
```

Comment: I get "tags" is not defined. Where do I define tags in conf.py?

Answer (score 1):

`conf.py` is a python module and `extensions` is a list, so you can simply append an extension to `extensions` based on a condition:

```
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc', 'sphinx.ext.doctest']

my_condition = 1

if my_condition == 1:
    extensions.append('sphinx.ext.htmlmath')
elif my_condition == 2:
    extensions.append('sphinxcontrib-mathml')
elif my_condition == 3:
    extensions.append('sphinx.ext.mathjax')
else:
    print "Didn't found a suitable extension"
```

However you have to know your condition before the build process starts.

Comment: But how would You pass `my_condition` to the `conf.py`? `conf.py` is eaten by the `sphinx-build`, not by `python`. Regarding `MathJax` - it takes much too long to load as the number of equations grows. And also You either - have to be on-line, or carry 6 Mb of fonts with every sphinx document meant to be readable by anyone else. `sphinxcontrib-mathml` does beatiful math with none of these issues. I also need `htmlmath` because I'm forced to render pdf with `wktpdftohtml` which doesn't support mathml.

Comment: A simple solution would be to read a file in `conf.py`, in which you write the extension name. Another one could be to use an environment variable you set before. Or use a wrapper script that prepares `conf.py` or the environment variables and than calls `make html`. (I understand your problems with mathjax now).